# convert remote object result to array collection in flex

Tags: php, apache-flex, air

HI guys,
 im using zend_amf and flex. My problem is i have to populate my advance datagrid using array collection. this array collection have a children.

example:

```
    [Bindable]
 private var dpHierarchy:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([
  {trucks:"Truck", children: [
         {trucks:"AMC841", total_trip:1, start_time:'3:46:40 AM'},
         {trucks:"AMC841", total_trip:1, start_time:'3:46:40 AM'}])
         ]};
```

but the datasource of my datagrid should come from a database, how can i convert the result from remote object to array collection that has the same format like in my example, or any other way.

here is my advance datagrid

```
<mx:AdvancedDataGrid id="datagrid"
                         width="500" height="200" lockedColumnCount="1" lockedRowCount="0" horizontalScrollPolicy="on" includeIn="loggedIn" x="67" y="131">
        <mx:dataProvider>
            <mx:HierarchicalData id="dpHierarchytest" source="{dp}"/>
        </mx:dataProvider>
        <mx:groupedColumns>
            <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="trucks"
                                       headerText="Trucks"/>
            <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="total_trip"
                                       headerText="Total Trip"/>
            <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumnGroup headerText="PRECOOLING">
                <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumnGroup headerText="Before Loading">
                    <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="start_time" headerText="Start Time"/>
                    <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="end_time" headerText="End Time"/>
                    <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="precooling_time" headerText="Precooling Time"/>
                    <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="precooling_temp" headerText="Precooling Temp"/>
                </mx:AdvancedDataGridColumnGroup>
                <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumnGroup headerText="Before Dispatch">
                    <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="bd_start_time" headerText="Start Time"/>
                    <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="bd_end_time" headerText="End Time"/>
                    <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="bd_precooling_time" headerText="Precooling Time"/>
                    <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="bd_precooling_temp" headerText="Precooling Temp"/>
                </mx:AdvancedDataGridColumnGroup>
                <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="remarks"
                                           headerText="Remarks"/>
            </mx:AdvancedDataGridColumnGroup>
            <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumnGroup headerText="Temperature Compliance">
                <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="total_hit" headerText="Total Hit"/>
                <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="total_miss" headerText="Total Miss"/>
                <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="cold_chain_compliance" headerText="Cold Chain Compliance"/>
                <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="average_temp" headerText="Average Temp"/>
            </mx:AdvancedDataGridColumnGroup>
            <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumnGroup headerText="Productivity">
                <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="total_drop_points" headerText="Total Drop Points"/>
                <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="total_delivery_time" headerText="Total Delivery Time"/>
                <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="total_distance" headerText="Total Distance"/>
            </mx:AdvancedDataGridColumnGroup>
            <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumnGroup headerText="Trip Exceptions">
                <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="total_doc" headerText="Total DOC"/>
                <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="total_eng" headerText="Total ENG"/>
                <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="total_fenv" headerText="Total FENV"/>
                <mx:AdvancedDataGridColumn dataField="average_speed" headerText="Average Speed"/>
            </mx:AdvancedDataGridColumnGroup>
        </mx:groupedColumns>
    </mx:AdvancedDataGrid>
```

Thanks, and i really need some help.

Answer (score 1):

Best way to do this is to use the Flash Builder's debug mode to see exactly what data is comthing through.

Naming conventions can be set from the SQL query as well if they don't match you're MXML labelFields or just rename the labelFields.

To convert the result of a ResultEvent, generally it's enough to do this:
myArrayCollection=event.result as ArrayCollection;

If returned data is Array, I found that you need to do this:
myArrayCollection=new ArrayCollection(event.result);

Hope this helps.